# Load balancing based on header value

Tags: apache-2.4, load-balancing, mod-proxy

I have apache2 load balancing working perfectly based on session affinity. Traffic does get directed properly to appropriate tomcat server.

We are trying to use same servers to serve some REST API calls. These calls don't have a session, however tomcat honoring the request does maintain some state and we would like to redirect the traffic to same tomcat based on some header value.

Tried searching and reading documents from apache web site, but have not figured it out yet.

Can I load balance based on header value?

Comment: From the [`mod_proxy_balancer`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html#example) docs, it looks like this should be possible, in conjunction with `mod_headers`.  Balancing based on HTTP headers is often called "sticky sessions"; searching for those terms might also turn up some solutions.